# StripeJS error: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, stripe-payments

This question has been asked before but there is no prominent solution on either of the links and the problem still persists after trying all the methods provided in the links. I am trying to generate a stripe subscription plan and each time I go through the process I get the error as "This customer has no attached payment source." As you can see in the screenshot that the stripe_card_token also gets generated and I have console.log the token also from JS and that also gets generated. I have attached all the relevant code files.

Github link for this project: https://github.com/arpit016/picture-app

Stripeerror screenshot

[image]

user.rb file

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :plan
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :source => stripe_card_token,
        :email => email,
        :plan => plan_id
      )

      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end

end
```

users.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));

    $('#form-submit-btn').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
        var error = false;
        if (!error) {
            Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_user'), stripeResponseHandler);
        }
        return false;
    }); //form submission

    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response){
        if (status == 200){
            //Get a reference to the form
            var f = $('#new_user');

            //Get the token from the response
            var token = response.id;
            console.log("Token:" + token);

            //Add the token to the form
            f.append('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]" value="' + token + '" />');
            console.log(f)

            //Submit the form
            f.get(0).submit();
        }
        else {
            $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).show();
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
        }
    }
});
```

Devise Modified Registrations controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_filter :select_plan, only: [:new]

   def create
      super do |resource|
          if params[:plan]
              resource.plan_id = params[:plan]
              if resource.plan_id == 2
                  resource.save_with_payment
              else
                  resource.save
              end
          end
      end
   end

   def select_plan
      unless params[:plan] && (params[:plan] == '1' || params[:plan] == '2')
        flash[:warning] = "Please select a valid membership"
        redirect_to root_url
      end
   end


end
```

Comment: @Deepak I have seen that link and I am already using source instead of card while creating customer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. A rails rookie mistake. I had not updated my application_controller.rb file which should contain below lines for devise:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:stripe_card_token])
  end
```